# How to change the width of the UITablewViewCell with autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

In one of my tableview i'm using a custom view created with a XIB file.
The tableview is correctly resized with autolayout, but the width of the cell is fixed.
In particular i saw that the ContentView is fixed to 320 px (the size used on the xib file).

Is there a way to use autolayout to change this value?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't set any constraints in your custom cells. The cell itself isn't the problem I guess, usually the container view is. So lets say you created the cell to fit the iPhone and it looks cut off on iPad, it most certainly because the UILabel or UITextView or any other element in the XIB isn't configured to stretch according to its constraints.

There's this beautiful [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) by ray wenderlich, if you wanna learn more about auto-layout and how constraints secure that your app looks good on any device

If you need further help, just let me know!

Comment: There is a lot of contraints inside the cell, this is not the problem. The problem is how to define a contraint between the contains view and the tablewiew.

Comment: There's no need to afaik, the cell is rendered automatically to the broader width, it's just about the container view. Usually just set leading, trailing, top and bottom to superview and that's almost it. I don't know if I get your point, can you please provide screenshots of simulator and xib?